# Upgrading Published Android App's minSdk

Tags: java, android, versioning

I have an app in Google Play which currently has a min-sdk of 8 and I'm planning to upgrade it into min-sdk of 14.

I already know that 'existing' users(devices of sdk 8) won't be able to get notified of the update(based on the filtering process made by Google Play which can be found on this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)).

I also know that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687977/min-sdk-greater-than-previous-versions-android) is somewhat related but just tackled on 'existing' users. What I'm hoping to know is that if 'new' users(devices of sdk 8) can still be able to search and view the previous apk(of min-sdk 8) after I publish the most updated apk(min-sdk of 14)?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18687977/3020568

Comment: @deniz thanks for the link but the accepted answer just tackled about 'existing' customers. How about 'new' customers? Will they still see the previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just put a version to the store with API level 14, than every device below this level should not be able to find the app.

But you can use the [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) of Android.
So you are able to create new versions of your app for a specific API level, without influencing e.g. older api versions.